# A basis for the weakest topology containing a set

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $S$ is a set, $\mathcal W \subset 2^S$, $\tau$ the weakest topology on $S$ containing $\mathcal W$.

A remark in Singer-Thorpe (see below), placed immediately after the theorem of existence of a weakest topology on $S$ containing $\mathcal W$, claims that the set

\begin{equation}
\mathcal B = \{ U_1 \cap \dots \cap U_k ; U_j \in \mathcal W, j = 1, \dots, k, \mbox{ where }k \mbox{ is any positive integer}\}
\end{equation}

is a basis for $\tau$. They actually add, after the assignment of $\mathcal B$: (*Throw in $\emptyset$ and $S$*). As exercise, they request to prove the remark.

Now, if the meaning of advice in round brakets is "consider the set $\mathcal B' = \mathcal B \cup \{ \emptyset, S\}$ and prove that $\mathcal B'$ is a basis for $\tau$", then the conclusion is straightforward. (the axioms in definition of basis are almost trivially satisfied.) If otherwise, I see no way to get both a covering for $S$ and $\emptyset \in \mathcal B$. In particular, I see no reason why we should have $\displaystyle\bigcup_{B \in \mathcal B} B = S$, since $\mathcal W$ is a generic family of subset of $S$. However, I'm quite a newbie in topology. Moreover, authors' style is rather brilliant and even informal in some point, so I make a little confusion sometimes.

So, have I correctly interpreted the round brakets or are there more subtle issues?

**Reference.** I.M. Singer, J.A. Thorpe, *Lecture notes on Elementary Topology and Geometry*, section 1.5.

Comment: There's no need to have $\varnothing$ in a basis, since $\varnothing = \bigcup\limits_{i \in \varnothing} U_i$. One may need to throw in $S$, although if by "positive" the authors mean non-negative, then $S = \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^0 U_i$ is automatically in $\mathcal{B}$ if the convention that the intersection of an empty family of sets is the "universe of discourse" is followed.

Comment: I am confused. Isn't the weakest topology containing $\mathcal W$ just $\{ \emptyset, \mathcal W, S\}$?

Comment: @Alexander $\mathcal W$ is not a subset of $S$ but a family of subsets of $S$ (i.e.,  subset of $2^S$).

Comment: Ah thanks. Somehow I missed that.

Comment: @DanielFischer First of all, thank you. Secondly, I agree with second part of your comment, but I don't understand the first one. Probably, we use slightly different definitions of basis, since for me (i.e. for Singer-Thorpe) $\varnothing \in \mathcal B$ is an axiom of basis and union are taken over subsets of $\mathcal B$, not over a set of indices. If I'm not wrong, equivalence follows from Axiom of choice.

Comment: Ah, different definitions of basis then. For me, a basis of a topology $\mathcal{T}$ is a subset $\mathcal{B}\subset\mathcal{T}$ such that every $U \in \mathcal{T}$ is a union of elements of $\mathcal{B}$, $U = \bigcup \{ B\in\mathcal{B} : B \subset U\}$. Then $\varnothing$ need not be in a basis.

Comment: My bad. I should have been more specific about the definition. On the other hand, in this way I've learned something new! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let we point out the notion of basis in use:

> **Definition.** Let $S$ be a set. The set $\mathcal B \subset 2^S$ is a *basis* for a topology on $S$ if the following conditions are satisfied:
>
> 1. $\varnothing \in \mathcal B$;
> 2. $\displaystyle\cup_{B \in \mathcal B} B = S$;
> 3. if $B_1$ and $B_2 \in \mathcal B$, then $B_1 \cap B_2 = \cup_{B \in \tilde{\mathcal B}} B$ for some subset $\tilde{\mathcal B} \subset \mathcal B$.

An equivalent definition is given in comments

> **Definition.**  A *basis* of a topology $\tau$ is a subset $\mathcal B \subset \tau$ such that every $U \in \tau$ is a union of elements of $\mathcal B$, $U=\cup \{ B \in \mathcal B : B \subset U \}$.

Although they are equivalent, for this special case they lead to slightly different conclusions. As explained in comments, with the latter is not necessary to require that $\varnothing \in \mathcal B$, since $\varnothing = \cup_{i \in \varnothing} B_i$. Thus we don't need to throw $\varnothing$ in $\mathcal B$. (that is, just take $U = \varnothing$ and take union over it. $\varnothing \in \tau$ since $\tau$ is a topology.) Assuming the first one, this is not possible: we must prove that $\varnothing \in \mathcal B$. The difference is that in the first approach $\mathcal B$ is used to generate a topology $\tau$, in the second $\mathcal B$ is extracted from a given topology $\tau$.

In both cases, we have to throw in $S$. This would not be the case if $k$ could be zero, but this is excluded by declaration of $\mathcal B$. Thus the conclusion is that we have to consider the set $\mathcal B' = \mathcal B \cup \{ \varnothing, S\}$ if we accept the first definition and $\mathcal B'' = \mathcal B \cup S$ if we choose the second, but in any case it is now obvious that $\mathcal B'$ (or $\mathcal B''$) satisfies the axioms of the definition.